# how to run mysql stored procedure using java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a mysql stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER //  
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRecordsByAge(IN Age INT)  
BEGIN 
  SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE age = Age;  
END //  
DELIMITER ;
```

When I run this stored procedure through java then it is giving all records of the table.

But if I have a condition in select statement. Why this is happening?

here is set of lines of my code:-

```
CallableStatement cStmt = null;
cStmt = con.prepareCall("{ CALL GetSpecificRecord(?) }");
cStmt.setInt(1, 25);
cStmt.execute();
ResultSet rs1 = cStmt.getResultSet();
```

When I print this result set this will give all records of the table.

Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: you are calling GetSpecificRecord, but your proc is GetRecordsByAge

Comment: Have you tried testing the sp in mysql itself.. Are you getting the desired result?
Iswanto spotted it!!

Answer (score 10):

The reason why you are getting all records is because of *column name collision* causing the `WHERE` clause to be always true. Change the name of the parameter that is not the same with the name of the column you are comparing with,

```
DELIMITER //  
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRecordsByAge(IN _Age INT)  
BEGIN 
  SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE age = _Age;  
END //  
DELIMITER ;
```

The second is, you are calling different stored procedure. instead of `GetRecordsByAge`, you are calling `GetSpecificRecord`.

Answer (score 4):

Because the condition `WHERE age = Age` is always ture.

Change the parameter name `Age` to something else:

```
DELIMITER //  
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRecordsByAge(IN AgeParam INT)  
BEGIN 
  SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE age = AgeParam;  
END //  
DELIMITER ;
```